# How to build python telegram bot?

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, instagram-api, python-telegram-bot

I'm learnning python and i want to develop my self.
I want to do this using **telegram bot** how can do it?
For example i want to build un **instagram video downloader**. could you help me how to do that , from where i shall start , which library shoud using and so on.

Answer (score -1):

I found a simple library it's name : telepota.
it's not what i wanted exactly and not famous but it looks like better for one who learn python and want to practice more.

The library founder said that:
This project aims to simplify telegram bot development using higher level classes and functions which are easy to understand and implement. I took over development and maintenance from nickoala who was the author of this beautiful project.

Then if some one want to try it , this is the link in github:
https://github.com/codingsett/telepota.

if someone have another libraries or ideas , i'll be thankful.